# Cypress reuse test cases in multiple test suites

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

I am new to Cypress and trying out one POC.

The application I am working on requires me to test the same component in different test suites. Is there any why in which I can avoid rewriting the same chunk of code, like using function?

```
export function testWelcomeBanner() {
    ...
 welcomeBanner.should('have.text', 'welcome');
    ...
}
```

I did try some ways, like trying to call this function from it block in test suites etc. but received errors. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use custom commands to reuse your scripts. You can read more about custom commands from the [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax).

You can write your reusable functions under `cypress/support/command.js`

```
Cypress.Commands.add('welcomeBanner', (text) => {
  cy.get('locator').should('have.text', 'text');
})
```

You can use the above command in any of your tests like

```
cy.welcomeBanner('Welcome Text')
```

Answer (score 12):

Cypress recommends using functions just as you would with plain old JavaScript.

> ...writing Cypress tests is JavaScript, and it's often more efficient to write a function for repeatable behavior.

[Source](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Best-Practices)

Put reusable functions into a separate file.

`utils.js`:

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

export function testWelcomeBanner() {
  // Add more logic as needed here. You can also return
  // the result of your `cy.` call.
  cy.get("div.welcomeBanner")
    .should("have.text", "welcome");
}
```

Then import those functions in your Cypress tests.

`myTest.spec.js`:

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />
import { testWelcomeBanner } from "../utils.js"; // Adjust the path for your environment

describe("testing", () => {
  it("can do something", () => {
    ...
    testWelcomeBanner();
    ...
  });
});
```

Comment: If the separate file is created under same Cypress test folder (e.g. integration) , I found myself also need to specify [included or excluded files](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#excludeSpecPattern) in Cypress configure so they won't get picked up by the test runner